# $\mathbb F_q[x]/(p(x))$ is a field of order $q^n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

Let $\mathbb F_q$ be a field of order $q$ and $p(x)$ be an irreducible element in $\mathbb F_q$ of degree $n$. Then prove that $\mathbb F_q[x]/(p(x))$ is a field of order $q^n$.

Attempt:

As $p(x)$ is irreducible element in $\mathbb F_q[x]$ therefore ideal generated by $p(x)$ will be maximal and hence $\mathbb F_q[x]/(p(x))$ is a field.

Now, $\mathbb F_q[x]/(p(x))$ is a vector space over $\mathbb F_q$.

Let $\deg p(x)=n$. Then $\mathbb F_q[x]/(p(x))$  will be a **n-dimensional** vector space over $\mathbb F_q$.

Then as our field is of dimension $q$, so $\mathbb F_q[x]/(p(x))$  will have $q^n$ elements.

This is my outline. I can fill the details. I just want to know whether I am on right track or not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I think that argument works.

I should add that in the general case, *every* finite field is $\mathbb F_{q^n}$ for some $n$, so as soon as you knew as it was a field and contained $\mathbb F_q$ you were in principal done. So you don't even need $p$ to be irreducible here! (You wouldn't necessarily have that $n = \deg p$, in that case.)

Answer (score 0):

Let $F[x]=\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(p(x)) = \{h(x): \deg(h) \leq p(x)\}$. If we let $n = deg(p)$ then we have all polynomials of the form;

$$a_{n}x^{n}+ a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0 \in F[x]$$

Now its just a simple counting argument to say that you have $q^n$ polynomials.